# Migrating async_trait with Box to the new async_fn_in_trait feature

Tags: rust

I would like to migrate `async_trait`-based code to the new [async traits feature](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/115822) (to be released in Rust 1.75).  My existing legacy code:

```rust
#[async_trait::async_trait]
pub trait SourceOld: Send {
    async fn get_async(&self) -> Result<String, ()>;
    fn clone(&self) -> Box<dyn SourceOld>;
}

pub fn process_old_sources(_sources: Vec<Box<dyn SourceOld>>) {
    todo!()
}
```

Rewriting it as...

```rust
pub trait SourceNew: Send {
    async fn get_async(&self) -> Result<String, ()>;
    fn clone(&self) -> Box<dyn SourceNew>;
}

pub fn process_new_sources(_sources: Vec<Box<dyn SourceNew>>) {
    todo!()
}
```

Compiling it produces this error for both `Box<dyn SourceNew>` usages.

```
error[E0038]: the trait `SourceNew` cannot be made into an object
  --> src/lib.rs:10:28
   |
10 |     fn clone(&self) -> Box<dyn SourceNew>;
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `SourceNew` cannot be made into an object
   |
note: for a trait to be "object safe" it needs to allow building a vtable to allow the call to be resolvable dynamically; for more information visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety>
  --> src/lib.rs:9:14
   |
7  | pub trait SourceNew: Send {
   |           --------- this trait cannot be made into an object...
8  |     // fn get_async(&self) -> impl std::future::Future<Output = Result<String, ()>> + Send;
9  |     async fn get_async(&self) -> Result<String, ()>;
   |              ^^^^^^^^^ ...because method `get_async` is `async`
   = help: consider moving `get_async` to another trait
```

The nightly compiler also suggests to replace `get_async` with this, but that seems to be fine.

```
fn get_async(&self) -> impl std::future::Future<Output = Result<String, ()>> + Send;
```

Comment: Maybe check under the *"What isn't stabilized (aka, potential future work)" - Dynamic dispatch* header in the linked pr, `async fn` in traits objects are not implemented yet and will also not be stabilized, I suggest you follow one of the compilers recommendations. (Or stick with `async_trait` for those traits that do need to be dispatched dynamically)

Comment: thx, i didn't notice that section (that ticket description is pretty big).  I am not sure how to restructure the code to follow the compiler suggestions. I have multiple implementers of `Source` trait. I store them in a  hashmap, so that I can call the async method the same way for all implementers.

Comment: Then you're stuck with `async_trait` or something similar for the time being

Comment: thx.  I am a bit surprised with the -1 -- wouldn't migrating away from async_trait be something everyone will want to do? I'm sure i won't be the only person stuck with this issue... Plus an in-depth explanation would help with understanding the reasons its not supported (the ticket does mention it but not clear to those outside of compiler space)

Comment: I can only guess but it might be the "does not show any research effort" bit of the DV explanation that led to the DV seeing as the answer can be found by just reading what you linked yourself.

Comment: Sigh, I wrote a whole sample test code to narrow down the issue and provide an easy-to-understand example... And did a bunch of research without realizing the answer was hiding in the original post. Oh well :shrug:

Comment: @YuriAstrakhan You shouldn't let a lone downvote affect you. Plus I think an answer here would be valuable to explain that the new language feature is not a replacement (yet). I bet you won't be the only one thinking so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`async_fn_in_trait` is not yet a complete replacement for `async-trait`, and not everyone can use it. The feature stabilized is a MVP, and should be extended in the future.

Two features are not stabilized: dynamic dispatch, and constraining the future at call site.

Dynamic dispatch means allowing to use a trait containing `async fn` or a method returning `impl Trait` as `dyn Trait`. Constraining the future at call site means, assuming you have `async fn foo()`, being able to specify for a method that takes `impl ThatTrait` that the future that `foo()` returns is `Send` (for example). In the same way, the ability to constrain the return type of `impl Trait` returning methods is also not stabilized.

Those features are not currently stabilized because they're big and complex and have questions about their design. I'll try to explain shortly why.

Dynamic dispatch is not implement at all (as of time of writing) since it is not clear how to implement it. `async fn`s in traits are desugared to functions with an associated type for the returned future, but the associated type can be different for different implementations and have different size on stack, so just like with regular associated types we cannot call this method on `dyn Trait`.

`async-trait` solves that by boxing the returned future. However, for the language solution we want to avoid boxing in the statically dispatched case. So this requires a conversion of some kind between the non-boxing and the boxing methods. It is not yet clear how this conversion should be implemented, especially since we don't want implicit allocations. [Niko Matsakis has wrote a series on this subject titled "Dyn async traits"](https://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2021/09/30/dyn-async-traits-part-1/).

Constraining the future is implemented in a small form (called RTN, Return Type Notation) but it is not clear this is what we want to end with. It is not clear what syntax is best for constraining it, since this is a new thing (there is nowhere else in Rust where we refer to the return type of a method generically) and what will be the semantics. [Niko wrote a series about that too](https://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2023/02/01/async-trait-send-bounds-part-1-intro/).

In conclusion, async fn in traits is suitable for people who don't need dynamic dispatch and don't need to constrain the future (for example, people on embedded, or some times in other places too). Others should stay with `async-trait`, and wait for more to stabilize.